# why should we disable interrupts for critical sections

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I am a beginer in the synchronization,and i have some problems in the  critical sections and i konw that lock the  critical sections can ensure the synchronization.

```
// Some Code
Acquire_lock(){disable Interrupts;}
Critical section   //Interrupt occurs and arrives to acquire the same lock.
Release_lock(){enable Interrupts;}
```

My question is :why disable the interrupts when acquire the lock for the  critical sections?

Answer (score 1):

Note the following applies to Unix/Linux, not sure if it is valid for Windows as well.

if you acquire a lock, the lock is "owned" by the current process. I.e. other processes are blocked if they try to take the same lock.

Since locks are owned by the process as a whole, they don't suffice to effectively stop simultaneous access **inside** the process. (this counts for concurrent threads and interrupt handlers).

For instance suppose a process acquires a lock, then an interrupt happens. This leads to the interrupt handler for that signal to be invoked, possibly in the middle of your critical section. Now suppose the interrupt handler tries to acquire the same lock (because it wants to invoke the same critical section too). This will work (because the process already *has* the lock).

In other words interrupt handlers will not be stopped by locks taken by the main thread. So for the main thread's lock to be effective, the interrupt handlers must be temporarily stopped as well.

Note for multi-threaded applications in Unix/Linux there is a different set of system calls to synchronize so the above is more an issue for interrupt handlers in a single threaded application than for concurrent threads.

Note: the order should be

1. disable interrupts
2. take lock
3. perform critical code
4. unlock
5. enable interrupts

Comment: shouldn't locks not be used in the interrupts in the first place? if so, is there still a need to disable interrupts?!

Comment: in general, if you don't use locks in the interrupt code, and you otherwise don't interfere with the state of your critical code, then I would say you don't need to disable them.